# Says "Expecting more source characters"

Tags: javascript, jquery

That code below gives an error "Expecting more source characters" you may please any help me on this issue.

Thanks

Cengiz Yücel
A web developer form Turkey

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("a#aDevam").hover(function () {
                $("div#SekmeBtn").css({ 'background-image': 'url(images/SekmeButonDevam.jpg)'
                });
            }, function () {
                var cssObj = { 'background-color': '#ddd' }
                $("div#AA").css(cssObj);
            });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 5):

"Expecting more source characters" normally indicates a line that's not terminated and there is one.

```
var cssObj = { 'background-color': '#ddd' }
```

needs a semicolon.

Comment: Thankyou. I did settled your recomendation and some other corrections. Now It does not give any error message but it is unfortunately not working either. my final coding like tis below

Comment: That a different question really. How does it not work and why weren't you just using the CSS hover selector in your CSS classes?

Answer (score 0):

check unclosed braces or missed semicolon inside your java script snippet. I got this error whenever I missed a closing brace for a function inside the 'script' tag.

Answer (score 0):

Another common source that catches C programmers is the opening brace on functions -- (most) javascript programmers put it at the end of the line and (most) C programmers start it on a new line. Doing both is obviously an error:

```
MyClass.LastFunctionInFile = function() {
{
    Foo();
    Bar();
}
```

See it?